# insert into select statment inner join

Tags: sql, sql-server

I have two valuues which I want to insert into table
first value I select from the another table using join technique but I have problem to insert another value can any body help me please?

My query is

```
INSERT INTO installment(cp_id,I_income)
SELECT cp_id,customer.c_id,customer.CNIC 
FROM customer 
INNER JOIN installment
    on installment.cp_id=customer.c_id 
WHERE customer.CNIC=1210
```

Now I want to just put the i_income field value=4000 how I can do this?

Comment: It's impossible to follow the question like this. Please provide some sample data and the result you want to achieve - and properly format your post. Thanks!

Comment: Please edit your question and provide sample data and desired results.

Comment: Please see below my earlier comment - we need more details from you to be able to answer this question.

Answer (score 0):

I think you're looking for something like this (if I understand your question properly):-

```
INSERT INTO installment(cp_id,I_income)
SELECT cp_id,4000 
FROM customer 
INNER JOIN installment
    on installment.cp_id=customer.c_id 
WHERE customer.CNIC=1210
```

Comment: i want to put i_income value from text box

Comment: What text box?  You really should be mentioning details like this in your original question. My suggestion is that you edit your question and include ALL details that might help us to get you the answer you need.

Comment: i done this Mat Richardson your query really help me how can i say thanks to u i have no words thanxxx lotttt.....................